# My finetuned huggingface model breaks when I save it and load it

Tags: tensorflow, data-science, huggingface

I used this line of code to save my model.

```
roberta_model.save('saved_models/')
```

Then this line of code to load my model.

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_models/')
```

But when I run the predict function with this line of code...

```
test_input = roberta_tokenizer('I want to kill myself', padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='tf')
test_input_ids = test_input["input_ids"]
test_attention_mask = test_input["attention_mask"]
predictions = loaded_model.predict([test_input_ids, test_attention_mask])
print(predictions)
```

It outputs this error.

```
ValueError: Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got: Positional arguments (11 total): * <tf.Tensor 'input_ids:0' shape=(1, 3) dtype=int32> * <tf.Tensor 'attention_mask:0' shape=(1, 3) dtype=int32> * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * False Keyword arguments: {} Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s): Option 1: Positional arguments (11 total): * {'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/attention_mask'), 'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/input_ids')} * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * False Keyword arguments: {} Option 2: Positional arguments (11 total): * {'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/attention_mask'), 'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/input_ids')} * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * True Keyword arguments: {} Option 3: Positional arguments (11 total): * {'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_mask'), 'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/input_ids')} * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * False Keyword arguments: {} Option 4: Positional arguments (11 total): * {'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_mask'), 'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/input_ids')} * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * None * True Keyword arguments: {}
```

I saw a couple of posts on the same error message, but I don't think it is the same case.

I tried using different combinations for saving and loading, but I am unsure which one is the right one.